# Erlang and SOAP services - A rock and a hard place

Tags: web-services, soap, erlang, mnesia, yaws

My question may first of all seem to have a duplicate but i have hit something that has suprised me. `Yaws Webserver` comes with a complete set SOAP example, but when i tried running it as is, this is what i get:
[image]

In text form, this is what i see in the shell:

```
1> inets:start().
ok
2> yaws_soap_lib:call("http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL","GetWeatherByPlaceName",["Boston"]).

=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Apr-2013::20:32:11 ===
Call to tuple fun {erlsom_parse,xml2StructCallback}.
Tuple funs are deprecated and will be removed in R16. Use "fun M:F/A" instead, for example "fun erlsom_parse:xml2StructCallback/2".
(This warning will only be shown the first time a tuple fun is called.)
{error,{decoding,"Malformed: Illegal character in prolog"}}

3> yaws_soap_lib:call("http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL","GetWeatherByPlaceName",["Boston"]).
{error,{decoding,"Malformed: Illegal character in prolog"}}
4>
```

You could try the yaws example following this [page](http://yaws.hyber.org/soap_intro.yaws).

 Another problem, is that i have tried other SOAP libraries like [detergent](https://github.com/devinus/detergent) and [erlsoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlsoap/) and they are either too old or completely un-usable. Most of the solutions, even yaws, mentions his dependency on `erlsom` i pretty think for the XML parsing. But, i can hardly use `erlsom` single-handedly to offer soap services. 
Somebody provide some information on how i can work with soap services (both a sa client and server) in erlang, and please explain the error i am getting with yaws. I am using the latest yaws version and erlang 15B.

Comment: I'm also playing with Erlang and SOAP right now. I have some problems with my own WS, but the Weather example worked out of the box. I'm using Erlang R15B02 and Yaws 1.94 on Linux.

Comment: let me change yaws version and see. Probably also because i am using Windows 7

Comment: still getting the same problem with `yaws-1.94`. Let me shift to linux and see the outcome. But, with R15B02, where you also getting the `fun` warning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, but here's how I deal with SOAP requests:

Write a function/module that wraps the following:

1. Set up some request templates (static XMLs) and fill them up with [erlydtl](https://github.com/evanmiller/erlydtl)
2. Make a HTTP POST request (using your client of choice) with `SoapAction` header set.
3. Take off the important stuff from the response using [erlsom](https://github.com/willemdj/erlsom)

Comment: true ! this works !. Thank you. I used `erlsom SAX` parsing to get out what i need from the requests. And i can construct the soap response back to the clients.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/otp_mibs/notes.html) we can read the following:

> Tuple funs (a two-element tuple with a module name and a function) are
>   now officially deprecated and will be removed in R16. Use 'fun M:F/A'
>   instead.

So, Yaws should be updated. As a workaround, you have at least two options:

1. the [Detergent](https://github.com/devinus/detergent) library
2. Or, if you don't mind using the (not so) older Erlang R15, I believe it should work, as other users reported.